# Reading CSV file to hash gives incorrect result

Tags: csv, perl

I have csv file containing (the SQL query is simplified):

```
SQL_QRY
"insert into TTL_CCL_DB_INF.D_1244_CRB_PARTY_EXT (CD_REC_PARTY, CD_REC_OBJECT_TYPE, T_FULL_NAME, ..) select * from TTL_CCL_DB_STG.D_1244_CRB_PARTY aa1 inner join TTL_CCL_DB_STG.D_1244_CRB_COMPANYFACT bb1 on aa1.CD_REC_PARTY = bb1.CD_REC_PARTY"
```

I have a perl script to read the file into hash:

```
sub somesub {
  ...
  my $fh;
  my $key;

  eval { open($fh, '<', $tmp_file); };

  if ($@) { 
    $errmsg = $@;
    croak {message=>$errmsg};
  };

  while(my $lines = <$fh>) {
    chomp $lines;
    my @data = split(/|/, $lines);
    $key = shift @data;
    $data_rt{$key} = \@data; 
  };
  close $fh;
  unlink $tmp_file;

  return %data_rt;
}
```

But the returned hash looks like:

```
 RETURN >>>>$VAR1 = {
' => [],  'SQL_QRY
          '"insert into TTL_CCL_DB_INF.D_1244_CRB_PARTY_EXT (CD_REC_PARTY, CD_REC_OBJECT_TYPE, T_FULL_NAME, CD_TAX_IDENTIFIER, CD_VAT_IDENTIFIER,DWH_TRANSFRM_ID, DWH_TRANSFRM_RUN_ID, DWH_BD, DWH_VSN_NO ) select aa1.CD_REC_PARTY, aa1.CD_REC_OBJECT_TYPE, aa1.T_FULL_NAME, bb1.CD_TAX_IDENTIFIER, bb1.CD_VAT_IDENTIFIER,  $transfrmId, \'$transfrmRunId\', cast(\'$bnsDt\' as date format \'YYYYMMDD\'), $occNbr from TTL_CCL_DB_STG.D_1244_CRB_PARTY aa1 inner join TTL_CCL_DB_STG.D_1244_CRB_COMPANYFACT bb1 on aa1.C' => []ARTY = bb1.CD_REC_PARTY and cast(aa1.DWH_BD as date format \'YYYYMMDD\') = \'$10000050_dwh_bd\' and aa1.DWH_VSN_NO = $10000050_vsn_no and cast(bb1.DWH_BD as date format \'YYYYMMDD\') = \'$10000034_dwh_bd\' and bb1.DWH_VSN_NO = $10000034_vsn_no"
        };
```

Would anybody help me how to do that correctly? I need to have it as much flexible as possible (csv file can contain more rows and more columns)

Comment: Is not necessary to build a parser for CSV in Perl. I suggest you to use this module from CPAN - https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS

That uses C library to parse so, is very fast!

Comment: If you have problems in your file, the parse will tell you!

Comment: Please see [webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and compare it to your data. I do not see that your data is in CVS format. At the same time code will splits input line on '|' which is not present anywhere in the data. Definitely mismatch in description, in code with provided input data.

Answer (score 1):

The sample data that you show us doesn't seem to match your code. The code wants to split the data on pipe symbols. But the data doesn't contain any pipe symbols. So I'm not sure how that's going to work.

However, I'm pretty confident that the problem is on this line:

```
my @data = split(/|/, $lines);
```

The first argument to `split()` is a regex. And a pipe symbol is a regex metacharacter. In order to use a metacharacter as itself, you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
my @data = split(/\|/, $lines);
```

Comment: the sample csv was created with this line `my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ( { binary => 1, sep_char => "|", eol => "\r\n" } )             
              or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();`, so there is one column name and one value (sql statement) I edited the `split` but it didn' help

Comment: @JanFi86, You should using be Text::CSV_XS to parse it too!

Comment: @JanFi86: But why is there no pipe character in the data that you've shown us?

Comment: @Dave Cross I don't know in the comment before is the code that generates the csv, I'm not that skilled in Perl

Comment: @JanFi86: Well, that's the code that creates the object that apparently generates the CSV data. But we haven't seen how it is used to actually create the CSV file. From that code snippet, it would appear to create a data file where a record is on one line with pipe characters separating the fields. But the data you've shown us is on two lines and doesn't contain a pipe character. I'm not sure how we are supposed to reconcile those facts. This isn't about being skilled in Perl. It's about recognising contradictions in what you are telling us.

Comment: I think that this problem comes down to this. Your question starts by saying "I have csv file containing..." but then you show us data that looks nothing like a CSV file.